# Leer una matriz en C

Tags: c, matriz

Tengo que crear un programa en C con el cual pueda leer una serie de nombres e introducirlos en una matriz MXN.

Ejemplo de matriz:

[image: Ejemplo de matriz]

El programa deberá dejar de pedir nombres cuando se escriba . o cuando se llegue a M nombres.

```
void leer(char nombres[M][N]){
    for(int i=0; i<M && nombres[i-1][0]!='.'; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N && nombres[i][j-1]!='\0'; j++){
            scanf("%c", &nombres[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que no los lee bien, ni siquiera cuando introduzco `.` para, creo que debe ser algo de los parámetros.  No para cuando se introduce `.` por lo que si dejo la condición `nombres[i-1][0]!='.'` no puedo ver que esta leyendo. Si quito esa condición, al pasar por `print_nombres(nombres);` imprime caracteres sin sentido, de todo tipo, aparecen desde letras tanto en mayúsculas y minúsculas como caracteres especiales (%, &, ...).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define M 100
#define N 100
void leer(char nombres[M][N]);
void print_nombres(char nombres[M][N]);
int main()
{
    char nombres [M][N];
    printf("Introduce los nombres, . para acabar");
    leer(nombres);
    print_nombres(nombres);
    //Por ahora no tengo mas codigo pero habria otras funciones por aqui
}

void print_nombres(char nombres[M][N]){
    for(int i=0; i<M && nombres[i-1][0]!='\0'; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N && nombres[i][j-1]!='\0'; j++){
            printf("%c", &nombres[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: que resultado obtienes cuando dices que no los lee bien

Comment: Deberías presentar un [mcve]. ¿ Como estás inicializando el *array* que le pasas como argumento a esa función ?

Comment: Por favor, los comentarios no son para aportar información. [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/407535/edit) tu pregunta y añada ahí toda la información que te soliciten. Recuerda que el que está pidiendo ayuda eres tú. Ayúdanos a ayudarte. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes leer los nombres como una cadena completa y evitarte el ciclo `for` interno. Para eso, usa el formato `"%s"` en el scanf.

Agregamos una variable lógical `final`, que ponemos en `1` cuando el usuario ingresa un `.` para señalar el fin de los datos. Ahí también aprovechamos de cambiar el `.` almacenado por una cadena vacía, y así marcar el fin de los datos.

No podemos controlar el ciclo preguntando por el elemento anterior, como en `nombres[i-1][0]!='.'`, ya que no hay elemento anterior para el primer elemento.

```
void leer(char nombres[M][N]){
    int final = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < M && !final; i++){
        scanf("%s", nombres[i]);
        if (nombres[i][0] == '.') {
            nombres[i][0] = 0;
            final = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

La función de imprimir también se puede reducir imprimiendo cadenas completas. También simplificados la condición de término, ya que simplemente detectamos una cadena vacia (`nombres[i][0] == 0`)

```
void print_nombres(char nombres[M][N]){
    for(int i=0; i < M && nombres[i][0]; i++){
            printf("%s\n", nombres[i]);
        }
    }
```

Con esos cambios queda funcionando OK.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!